# I hit a car a year ago and run away,

Tags: sin

My age 18. Hello so i  hit a car in a parking, nobody was there so i ran away,  a year ago , its probably like 50-100  worth of damage. Nothing that serius, but  regret that i was so stupid to run away. i didnt prayed then. So i had nothing to fear. Now i fear god.The problem is i dont know who i hit, so i cant just go to the guy to give him money. i want to die with no debt. is that even posible now?